# How do I run this 3D Java Application?

Tags: java, jpanel, panel, paint, paintcomponent

I'm quite new at this stuff so sorry by my noob question

So, I'm trying to run this code on netbeans https://github.com/rukayam/Cube but it doesn't have an main class, so I created one but the problem is, the class that contains the panel and the paint method is abstract (the Canvas.java) and I can't instantiate an abstract class... What should I do?

(from what I know about painting in Java, one should call/instantiate the class/object that contains the Panel/JPanel and the paint or paintComponent methods)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Lec04 class extends the `Canvas` class, and is instantiable.  But that there is no evidence that that code ever worked ... so good luck.

Answer (score 0):

What Stephen C says is true:  You could instantiate Lec04 which has all properties and every method except `void render()` inherited, and `void render()` implemented inside of it.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to instantiate Lec04 on my main class and call an "lec04.init();" but it gave me this error:

`code`"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at pkg3dcube3.Canvas.init(Canvas.java:55)
 at pkg3dcube3.Lec04.init(Lec04.java:18)
 at pkg3dcube3.Main.main(Main.java:25)
C:\Users\Wartogh\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)"`code`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#createImage%28int,%20int%29

lines 54 and 55 of your code say
   buf = createImage(700,700);
          bufG = buf.getGraphics();
but the documentation for Component says createImage may return null.
In your case, createImage seems to have returned null, so
buf.getGraphics() is trying to call a method on a null object.

Comment: The docs say it may be returning null because the Component is not displayable.  Try putting lines 54 and 55 in Lec04.init() instead, because Canvas is abstract, and maybe not be displayable.  I'm not sure if it'll work but it's worth a try.

Comment: Yeah, it still gives a null pointer exception at `bufG = buf.getGraphics();` after I put it in the `Lec04.init()` :/

Comment: Hi, instead of 
`buf = createImage(700,700)`
you could try
`buf = new Image().getScaledInstance(700,700,0)`
Although you should look into Image.SCALE_AREA_AVERAGING etc because the above method I think is intended to use one of those fields.
Note that I'm not sure this would do the same thing, but I guess it would do the same thing and it's certainly worth playing about with.
If it doesn't work then I won't be able to help you out because I don't know much about graphics stuff.
Sorry and good luck.